# stop in Rcpp function (as a part of a package) ends in debug mode

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I am testing the use of `stop` in a package using `Rcpp` and I see that when `stop` is used, the function exits into debug mode in `R`. For example, I am using the example function at the this [link](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/intro-to-exceptions/) (see `takeLog3` function, also pasted below)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double takeLog3(double val) {
    if (val <= 0.0) {           // log() not defined here
        stop("Inadmissible value");
    }
    return log(val);
}
```

The output of `takeLog3(-10)` is

```
> takeLog3(-10)
Error in takeLog3(-10) : Inadmissible value
Called from: takeLog3(-10)
Browse[1]>
```

and then I have to enter `Q` to exit out of debug mode. My question is, is that expected behavior? Secondly, how can I make `stop` statement to not go into debug mode, but quit the function completely after displaying the `stop` message?

Note that I see this behavior when `takeLog3` is included in a package. I don't see this behavior when I have this function outside of a package in a simple `.cpp` file, where the function simply shows the `stop` message and control returns back to the console but does NOT go into debug mode.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

PS: I just found that I get the behavior I need by using `Rf_error` instead of `stop`. Can anyone provide an informed opinion, as to which one is preferred? Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with `throw std::range_error("Inadmissible value");` from the same reference link you posted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Second question:  `stop()` calls `Rf_error()` to implement the behaviour you see.

First question: You end up in the debugger because the IDE (which you didn't name or mention) wants to be helpful.  Try it on the command-line in a standard R shell:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("bool myStop(std::string reason) { Rcpp::stop(reason); }")
R> myStop("tired")
Error in myStop("tired") : tired
R>
```

Ubuntu 18.10, R 3.6.0.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I see the difference in behavior from RStudio IDE when I try on the command line in a standard shell. Thanks for clarifying that `stop()` calls `Rf_error()`. Good to hear from the authoritative source!

Comment: Always a pleasure -- there is a lot to "grok" in all of this.  I think you can also tell RStudio to not drop you into debug mode...